# Freezing a div within a div

Tags: css, html, scroll

My basic layout is a couple of divs within a div - http://jsfiddle.net/nxPhy/ - I'm looking for a css way to have the const div always visible regardless of any horizontal scrolling of the parent div (so only the content div is actually scrolled).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to container, and remove floats and add `position: fixed;` to the block you want to fixate.

Result:

> http://jsfiddle.net/nxPhy/1/

Comment: I have actually tried exactly that, except I had `left:5px` instead of `left:5`, and then the div was positioned relatively to the page instead of its parent. Didn't realize it matters.

Comment: `left:5px` is more correct, my fault. If *the div was positioned relatively to the page instead of its parent*, it means that you did not applied `position:relative` to container.

Comment: But with `left:5px` is actually doesn't work even with `position:relative` in the container. See your example with that change (and a margin for the container) - http://jsfiddle.net/nxPhy/4/

Comment: O.o `left:5` is invalid CSS. In fact, you can remove it, [the result does not change](http://jsfiddle.net/nxPhy/6/). Anyway I do not understand why it does not work with `5px`. Maybe there's something about `position: fixed` I'm missing...

Answer (score 1):

You want to add:

```
position:fixed
```

to the div that you want fixed. Doing this will position this div and it's containing elements fixed.